# IOS UIScrollView zooming without an UIImageView

Tags: ios, xcode, uiscrollview, zooming

I'm working on an iOS project. And I'm creating a schedule page. This view has a UIScrollView and scroll view has so many bordered labels and labels are filled with the schedule content. I want my scroll view to be zoomed in and out. But when I check for how to zoom in and out in UIScrollView I always seen a function that has a return type as image view and this works only with an image view inside of scroll view. Is there any way to make a view with too many elements to be zoomable without having an image view ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ScrollViewDelegate has `viewForZoom` method with return type `UIView`, just create a custom view, create and add all elements to view, then add the view to scrollView, then return that view in the `viewForZoom` method.